# How to prevent automatic show toast message when creation app short cut on home screen in android i dont want message

Tags: android

```
     Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),    HomeScreen.class);      
        shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

        Intent addIntent = new Intent();
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "AIMS ICD");
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.aims));
        addIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false);
        addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
        getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);
```

this code is working fine but after shortcut creation this show message"Shortcut AIMS ICD created" i dont want this message

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, there is no way to prevent a default system Toast from appearing (source: [Dianne, Google Employee](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/Y6rhIXTMr8M))

Comment: but whats up app is creating icon without TOAST